# Почему после переадресации в Django url изменяется в консоли, но в браузере нет?

Tags: django, post, redirect

После redirect'а url изменяется в консоли, посему я сужу об успехе, однако в браузере ничего не происходит.

view.py

```
def tables(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        text = request.POST.get('data_table')
        table_to_file_str(text, 'methods/static/methods/json/tables.json')
        return redirect(reverse('result'))
    else:
        matrix = Matrix.objects.all()
        context = {'matrix': matrix}
        return render (request, 'methods/tables.html', context)

def result(request):
    return render(request, 'methods/result.html')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns =[
path('result/', result, name = 'result'),
path('tables/', tables, name='tables'),
```

В консоле:

```
    [01/Jul/2022 14:54:36] "POST /methods/tables/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
    [01/Jul/2022 14:54:36] "GET /methods/result/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5562
```

Если я делаю переадресацию на страницу 'result' по обыкновенной ссылке, все работает нормально. Как правильно сделать переадресацию по нажатию кнопки после POST-запроса?

Comment: Как вы отправляете POST-запрос? Что конкретно отображается в браузере в тот момент когда «ничего не происходит»?

Comment: @andreymal Страница рендерится. По нажатию кнопки отправляется post запрос с введёнными данными на сервер с помощью ajax'a. Далее мне нужно сделать переадресацию на другую страницу, однако этого не происходит.

Comment: «с помощью ajax'a» — ajax-запросы абсолютно никак не влияют на текущее состояние страницы. Если вы хотите изменить адрес или обновить содержимое страницы, вы должны делать это вручную в javascript-коде после ajax-запроса

Comment: @andreymal Понял, большое спасибо!